# Why does TypeScript not give a type error when passing in an object that contains more properties than the input type?

Tags: typescript

Why does the following piece of code not throw a type error?

```
const fn1 = (arg1: { key: number }) => {
  console.log(arg1);
}

// Works as expected
fn1({ key: 1 });

// But this gives no type error
fn1({ key: 1, a: 1 });
```

- Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=10&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmAjDAvDAFAQwE4HNEBcMA3gFAwUwDWApgJ5FgCuAtgEY3YA0pAvgJQoAfGUoxQkEABsaAOikhcWPIn59SpBInSjaDGIj5rSE6DAAmmKJlQlylPUUQ8xmJz16ak6S9eNA

I have read typescipt docs and google for some time , can't understand the scene!

Comment: the variable "data" is not satisfied with fn1's param, why't not show type error?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not throw an error because the input type `{ key: number }` is a minimum requirement, not a precise requirement. So if you throw in `{ key: 1, a: 1 }` there is no error, because it contains the `key` property, and that's enough.

If you throw in `{ a: 1 }`, then there is an error, because the minimum requirement is to have the `key` property.

If you want TypeScript to throw an error, then you could create a class or an interface instead.

```
class ExampleClass {
  constructor(readonly key: number) {}
}

interface ExampleInterface {
  key: number;
}

const fn1 = (arg1: ExampleClass | ExampleInterface) => {
  console.log(arg1);
}

// Now TypeScript will notify you of an error
fn1({ key: 1, a: 1 });

// But this won't.
fn1(new ExampleClass(1));
fn1({ key: 1 });
```